# How to keep origin sql unchanged as much as possible when optimizing sql by HepPlanner?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, apache-calcite

I want to optimize sql by RelNode and then convert it into SqlNode so that I can get sql string to execute. After validation and optimization by HepPlanner, I got relNode. here is my rules,

```
CoreRules.FILTER_INTO_JOIN,
CoreRules.FILTER_PROJECT_TRANSPOSE,
CoreRules.FILTER_SUB_QUERY_TO_CORRELATE,
CoreRules.FILTER_MERGE,
CoreRules.PROJECT_TABLE_SCAN,
CoreRules.PROJECT_INTERPRETER_TABLE_SCAN,
CoreRules.JOIN_CONDITION_PUSH,
CoreRules.JOIN_SUB_QUERY_TO_CORRELATE,
PruneEmptyRules.PROJECT_INSTANCE
```

And the sql string of sqlNode by RelToSqlConverter below,

```
Select 
CAST(c1 AS `INT64`),
COUNT(*),
COUNT(c3)
...
```

My Original sql string is below,

```
Select 
c1,
COUNT(c2),
COUNT(CAST(c3 AS Nullable(Float64))
...
```

And the input schema to HepPlanner as below,

```
rowType=RecordType:peek(BIGINT c1, INTEGER c2, STRING c3)
```

(types in physical clickhouse table is (NULLABLE(INT64) c1,  NULLABLE(INT32) c2, Nullable(String) c3))

My expectation is like this,

```
Select 
c1,
COUNT(c2)
COUNT(CAST(c3 AS Nullable(Float64))
...
```

How can I achieve this without type cast changed and no count(*) to keep origin sql unchanged as much as possible?